# How install driver for Wireless?

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu

I want to install Xubuntu with dual boot W8.

So I have downloaded Xubuntu and installed it, but when I want use it, it doesn't detect WIFI, but when I am connected with ethernet it does detect it.

So I have concluded, the driver is missing ?!

How can I install the appropriate driver for my WIFI ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$
```

Yeah, but rfkill is strange "Hard blocked"

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I edit my post with return command

Comment: The driver is already there. Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe  -r asus_nb_wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all` and test the wifi.

Comment: My wifi network is disabled in the top right menu in Xubuntu :(